# MATLAB: Converting a uint32 (4-byte) value to the corresponding IEEE single-precision floating-point form

Tags: matlab, binary, floating-point, ieee-754, double-precision

In MATLAB (r2009b) I have a uint32 variable containing the value 2147484101.

This number (its 4-bytes) has been extracted from a digital machine-vision camera in a grabbing process. According to what I understand it holds the single-precision form of the shutter-speed of the camera (should be close to 1/260s = 3.8ms).

How do I convert this 32-bit number to its IEEE single-precision floating-point representation - using what's available in MATLAB?

With mentioned value in variable *n*, I have tried using a combination of *nn=dec2hex(n,16)* and then *hex2num(nn)*. But it seems that *hex2num* expects the hexadecimal coding to be double-precision and not single as it is here. Atleast I am getting weird numbers with this method.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** Tried @Matt's answer below:

```
typecast(uint32(2147484101),'single') %# without swapbytes
typecast(swapbytes(uint32(2147484101)),'single') %# with swapbytes
```

Which gives:

```
ans =

  -6.3478820e-043

ans =

  -2.0640313e+003
```

I tried the IEEE 754 converter (JAVA applet) at http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatApplet/IEEE754.html.

Using:

```
format hex
typecast(uint32(2147484101),'uint8') %# without swapbytes
typecast(swapbytes(uint32(2147484101)),'uint8') %# with swapbytes
```

gives

```
ans =

   c5   01   00   80

ans =

   80   00   01   c5
```

Entering these bytes into the applet (hexadecimal) gives me the same numbers as MATLAB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you're saying is that the underlying bits represent a floating point number, but that you've got it stored as a uint32.

If that's that case, you can cast it (i.e. reinterpret the bits) as a single precision float using the typecast() function.

```
b = typecast(a, 'single')
```

where a is your variable.

See:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/typecast.html

Edited: not the cast function, the typecast function... My apologies!

Comment: Yep, it must be `typecast` and not `cast`. But I am not really getting values I hoped for. You see, I have no prior-knowledge about the numbers. I am not even sure I got them stored correctly :) I just cross-checked using a java applet. So your method is sound. +1 and accepted.

Comment: @Ole Thomsen Buus: It's hard to suggest what you might do differently without knowing the method by which you arrived at your uint32, or the specification of the file/device you're reading. Hopefully you'll figure out where it's going wrong...

Answer (score 2):

You could do the cast when you read the data in with fread().

Have a look for the precision argument, you could read it as the int32 number and store it as a single by doing

```
shut_speed=fread(fid,1,'int32=>single');
```

Comment: Yes that is also a possibility - had not thought of that one.